# Wordpress Taxonomy Archive BUG

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm hoping that Its just my tired eyes missing something and a fresh pair of eyeballs might catch what I'm missing.

I have a custom taxonomy with a slug of 'residential_project_types' that is assigned to a custom post type of residential_projects. I want to display all terms from the taxonomy, outputting the term name and link.

Its KIND OF working...

Instead of displaying a single term for each, it appears to be displaying a term for every post included in the term. This of course is creating duplicates. In addition, the HTML isn't displaying properly, causing weird overlapping of elements.

My hunch is something is messed up with the loop...? Haven't been able to figure it out though. Any and all helped is much appreciated!

Here's a link to the broken/buggy page:
http://desarch.robertrhu.net/residential/

Here's the code I've written:

```
<?php
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'residential_project_types',
        'orderby'    => 'count',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'fields'     => 'all'
    ) );
?>

<?php
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'residential_projects',
        'residential_project_types' => $term->slug
    );

    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <a class="property-thumb-link"
           href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>">
            <div class="property-thumb column medium-6 small-12">

                <img src="<?php the_field('category_image', $term); ?>"
                     alt="<?php the_field ('category_image_alt', $term); ?>" />

                <div class="property-thumb-title">
                    <h2>
                        <?php echo $term->name; ?>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
     <?php wp_reset_postdata();
    endwhile;
 endif; }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display terms from a custom taxonomy, I don't think you should use `WP_Query()` - which is for looping through posts.

Instead you can get your term objects using the `get_terms()` function, looping through them as shown below:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'residential_project_types',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );

// Temp output of terms so you can see what you're working with
// var_dump($terms);

// loop through all terms
foreach( $terms as $term ) {

    if( 0 === $term->count ) {

        // This $term has no posts attached to it - you may want to treat it differently.
        echo $term->name;

    } elseif( $term->count > 0 ) {

        // Build your term markup for terms that have posts attached
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
        ?>
        <a class="property-thumb-link" href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>">
            <div class="property-thumb column medium-6 small-12">
                <img src="<?php the_field('category_image', $term->term_id); ?>" alt="<?php the_field ('category_image_alt', $term->term_id); ?>" />
                <div class="property-thumb-title">
                    <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <?php

    }

}
```

You could also hide empty terms by setting `'hide_empty' => true` in `get_terms()` - you could then drop the conditional that checks for empty terms.

I'm assuming here that your ACF custom fields are attached to the term, so we need to pass `$term->term_id` as the second argument to `the_field()` - but I'm not really sure what you're doing with these fields. Hopefully this is enough to help you make progress.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response! No dice. I had a similar thought. Moved the reset to multiple locations and no change.

Comment: Hi - I think I misunderstood what you'rew trying to do. I'll amend my answer!

Answer (score 0):

I was terribly over complicating this. Here's my answer...

```
<?php $terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'residential_project_types',
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => true
) );

    foreach( $terms as $term ) :
?>

<a class="property-thumb-link"
   href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>">
    <div class="property-thumb column medium-6 small-12">

        <img src="<?php the_field('category_image', $term); ?>"
             alt="<?php the_field ('category_image_alt', $term); ?>" />

        <div class="property-thumb-title">
            <h2>
                <?php echo $term->name; ?>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```